# MySQL - 1 Master List Table Not IN Table 2 but IN Table 3

Tags: mysql, sql

Can you kindly help me with my query?

In my database, I have 3 tables,

```
Table 1 - Student Master List  (9 Records) 
Table 2 - AM  (4 Records)
Table 3 - PM  (3 Records)
```

Table 2 and table 3 have the same structure but Table 2 is more priority than Table 3, anyway

I want to see the records from Table 1 which are NOT IN Table 2 BUT there's a record IN Table 3. Table 2 (4) + Table 3 (3) = 7 Records

But how can I show the 2 records from the master list

> sample database

[image]

My query is something like this:

```
select * from table1 t1 
where (id, lname, fname, mname) NOT IN
    (select id, lname, fname, mname from table2) and 
      (id, lname, fname, mname)  IN 
    (select id, lname, fname, mname from table3)
```

But when I did this, It just shows some records from table 2 and table 3

Comment: I assume the IDs are equal across all three tables? Try a simple select * from table1 where id not in (select id from table2) and id in (select id from table3)

Comment: You could improve this question by including sample data and expected output as text. 10 records from master, 5 for am and 2 for pm would be suffiicent.

Comment: @AndyThompson Yes, they have same Ids in all three tables.  I also did that query but the 20 records still not appear

Comment: According to your logic you should only get 5 records returned so why should you get 20?

Comment: @P.Salmon I've updated my question, actually i'm having a problem with my logic, i need to get the 20 records (referring from the first post) from the master list

Comment: Records with ID 8 and 9 does NOT exist in table3 according to added sample database indicating they should not be included. To see records in t1 that does not exist in t2 but exists in t3 you can use above query. If you want a different result you need to post exactly what you want :) If you want records from t1 only do the same query and change both to "not in"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you just need to union table 2 and 3 and left join table 1 testing for null values

```
drop table if exists t1,t2,t3;
create table t1 (id int);
create table t2 (id int);
create table t3 (id int);

insert into t1 values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);
insert into t2 values (2),(3),(4),(5);
insert into t3 values (1),(6),(7);

select t1.* 
from t1 
left join
(select id from t2
union all 
select id from t3)s on s.id = t1.id
where s.id is null;

+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    8 |
|    9 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a common key among all tables which is `(id, lname, fname, mname)` below will work. If your common key is somewhat different, adjust `WHERE` clauses in both subqueries to only include the common key (column(s)).

Use `EXISTS` to include records present in table 3 and `NOT EXISTS` to exclude records present in table 2:

```
select *
from table1 t1
where 
  not exists (
    select 1
    from table2 t2
    where t1.id = t2.id and t1.lname = t2.lname and t1.fname = t2.fname and t1.mname = t2.mname)
  and exists (
    select 1
    from table3 t3
    where t1.id = t3.id and t1.lname = t3.lname and t1.fname = t3.fname and t1.mname = t3.mname)
```